# Keep error message of exe file which is created by Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am using Pyinstaller to create exe file from Python source code, and I keep the cmd window when the exe is running

```
python pyinstaller.py --onefile script.py
```

Whenever there is an error, the error shows on the cmd window but disappears very quickly, is there any way to keep the error message on the cmd window?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create a batch file. Inside of it, put:

```
C:\path\to\your\file.exe
pause
```

and double click the batch file. Alternatively, just open a cmd window, navigate to the directory containing the exe and run `yourExe.exe`.

Comment: Yes, navigate to the directory and run exe works,  thank you!